# Continuous function in a separated domain and co-domain under the subspace topology?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose you have a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ where $X = (-3,-1)\bigcup [3, 5]$ and $Y=[-1,-\frac{1}{3}]\bigcup [3,5]$. $X$ and $Y$ both given the subspace topology under standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. What does it mean for a function to be continuous under this map? Does the continuity under $(-3,-1)$ affect how the function should look like under $[3,5]$? Does $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x$ when $x< -1$ and $f(x)=x$ when $x\geq 3$ work? An example would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topological definition of continuity of a function $f : X \to Y$ states that $f$ is continuous when $f^{-1}(\mathcal{V})$ is open for all open subsets $\mathcal{V}$ of $Y$.

In this case, we have $X = (-3, -1) \cup [3, 5]$ and $Y = \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right] \cup [3, 5]$ under the subspace topology inherited from the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}$. What does this mean? An open subset of $X$ will take the form $\mathcal{U} \cap X$, where $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ is open (and similarly for $Y$). For example, the set $[3, 4)$ is open in $X$, as we may write
$$[3, 4) = (0, 4) \cap X.$$
Let's take your example
$$f : X \to Y: f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3}x & \text{if } x < -1 \\ x & \text{if } x \ge 3
\end{cases}.$$
This function is continuous! Let's prove it.

Suppose $\mathcal{V}$ is an open subset of $Y$. That is, there exists some open $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ such that
$$\mathcal{V} = \mathcal{U} \cap \left(\left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right] \cup [3, 5]\right) = \left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]\right) \cup (\mathcal{U} \cap [3, 5]).$$
Note that $\mathcal{V}$ has been expressed as the union of two (relatively) open subsets of $Y$, so we can consider them individually, and use the fact that
$$f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B).$$

Consider
$$f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]\right).$$
We wish to show that this set is open in $X$.

Let $\mathcal{U}' = 3 \mathcal{U} = \{3x : x \in \mathcal{U}\}$. It's not difficult to show that $\mathcal{U}'$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$; for any point $3x \in \mathcal{U}'$, there is an open ball centred at $x$ in $\mathcal{U}$. Triple the centre and the radius, and the resulting ball will lie in $\mathcal{U}'$.

I claim that
$$f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]\right) = \mathcal{U}' \cap (-3, -1) = (\mathcal{U}' \cap (-10, 0)) \cap X,$$
which proves the left hand side is open in $X$.

Note that
\begin{align*}
x \in X \setminus (-3, -1) &\implies x \in [3, 5] \\
&\implies f(x) = x \in [3, 5] = Y \setminus \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right] \\
&\implies x \notin f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]\right),
\end{align*}
or contrapositively,
$$f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]\right) \subseteq (-3, -1).$$
Moreover, if $x \in f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]\right)$, then this implies that $f(x) = \frac{1}{3}x$, as this is the definition of $f$ on $(-3, -1)$. So, for such $x$, we have $f(x) = \frac{1}{3}x \in \mathcal{U}$, so
$$x = 3\left(\frac{1}{3}x\right) \in \mathcal{U}'.$$
Thus,
$$f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]\right) \subseteq \mathcal{U}' \cap (-3, -1).$$

On the other hand, suppose $x \in \mathcal{U}' \cap (-3, -1)$. Note that $f(x) = \frac{1}{3}x$. Given $-3 < x < -1$, this means that $-1 < f(x) < -\frac{1}{3}$, so $f(x) \in \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]$.

Since $x \in \mathcal{U}'$, there exists some $u \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $x = 3u$. Thus $f(x) = u \in \mathcal{U}$. In total,
$$f(x) \in \mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right] \implies x \in f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]\right).$$
Hence, the inverse image of $\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]$ under $f$ is open.

A similar proof will also establish that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{U} \cap [3, 5])$ is open. Hence,
$$f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left(\left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right] \cup [3, 5]\right)\right) = f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U} \cap \left[-1, -\frac{1}{3}\right]\right) \cup f^{-1}(\mathcal{U} \cap [3, 5])$$
is open, and $f$ is continuous.

(Or you can treat $X$ and $Y$ as metric subspaces of $\Bbb{R}$ like a normal person!)

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for your time. This was very helpful :)

Comment: @mathlover314 No worries. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The subspaces $X_1 = (-3,-1)$ and $X_2 = [3,5]$ of $X$ are open in $X$ because $X$ has the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R$ and $X_1 = (-3,-1) \cap X$, $ X_2 = (1,6) \cap X$.

Now let us prove a more general result: Let $X_1,X_2$ be open subsets of a space $X$ such that $X = X_1 \cup X_2$. Then a function $f : X \to Y$ into a sapce $Y$ is continuous if and only if the restrictions $f \mid_{X_i} : X_i \to Y$ are continuous.

So let $f \mid_{X_i}$ be continuous. For any open $V \subset Y$ we get
$$f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(V) \cap (X_1 \cup X_2) = f^{-1}(V) \cap X_1 \cup f^{-1}(V) \cap X_1 = f \mid_{X_1}^{-1}(V) \cup f \mid_{X_2}^{-1}(V) .$$
Both $f \mid_{X_i}^{-1}(V)$ are open in $X_i$, hence also open in $X$. This shows that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$, i.e. $f$ is continuous.

The converse is trivial.

You can generalize this as follows. Let $X = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ with open $X_\alpha \subset X$. Then $f : X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if all restrictions $f \mid_{X_\alpha} : X_\alpha \to Y$ are continuous. This implies the following:

Let $f_\alpha : X_\alpha \to Y$ are continuous functions such that
$$(*) \phantom{xx} f_\alpha \mid_{X_\alpha \cap X_\beta} = f_\beta \mid_{X_\alpha \cap X_\beta} \text{ for any two } \alpha, \beta \in A$$
Then $f : X \to Y, f(x) = f_\alpha(x)$ for $x \in X_\alpha$, is a well-defined continuous function.

Note that $(*)$ is automatically satisfied if the $X_\alpha$ are pairwise 
disjoint. This applies to your question.